# Minimum cost of forming a magic square

Tags: matrices, discrete-optimization, magic-square

Hello i have a question regarding finding the minimum cost of converting a 3 x 3 matrix in to a magic square.

So i have a simple question, why can't we solve it by finding the sum of the each row then subtracting it from 15 (taking the absolute value)? I mean, each row should sum up to 15 anyway, right?

For a case like this:

4 5 8

2 4 1

1 9 7

the answer is 14 and not 12 but i don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum cost to make each row and column sum to $15$ is indeed $12$.  But that ignores the additional restriction of magic squares that each integer in $\{1,\dots,9\}$ should appear exactly once.

In fact, even imposing that the final values are in the interval $[1,9]$ (and not necessarily integer or distinct) yields minimum cost $14$.

Comment: How does it ignore that restriction? if you don't mind explaining further

Comment: Consider the starting matrix of all 5s (or any matrix that already sums to 15).  Your proposed transformation does nothing in that case and in particular does not avoid duplicates.

Comment: I see, thank you.